# Jquery replace table with

Tags: jquery, replace, html-table

I have this table:

```
<table class="catsTable" width="100%" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0" border="0">
  <tbody><tr>
    <td style="width:25%" class="catsTd" id="cid5" valign="top">
        <a href="/load/prison_break_online/sezonul_1/5" >Sezonul 1</a> <span class="catNumData" style="unicode-bidi:embed;">[6]</span>
    </td>
    <td style="width:25%" class="catsTd" id="cid6" valign="top"><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_2/6" class="catName">Sezonul 2</a> <span class="catNumData" style="unicode-bidi:embed;">[0]</span></td>
    <td style="width:25%" class="catsTd" id="cid7" valign="top"><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_3/7" class="catName">Sezonul 3</a> <span class="catNumData" style="unicode-bidi:embed;">[0]</span></td>
    <td style="width:25%" class="catsTd" id="cid8" valign="top"><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_4/8" class="catName">Sezonul 4</a> <span class="catNumData" style="unicode-bidi:embed;">[0]</span></td>
  </tr></tbody>
</table>
```

So it is possible to replace this with :

```
<ul id="menu-css">
    <li><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_2/6">Sezonul 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_3/7">Sezonul 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_4/8">Sezonul 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_5/9">Sezonul 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

I tried with:

```
<script>
    $($('.catsTable').find('td').get().reverse()).each(function(){
         $(this).replaceWith($('<li>'+$(this).html()+'</li>'))
    })
    $('.catNumData').remove();
</script>
```

but there still remains `<table><tbody><tr>`  or is not even possible something like this?

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply:

```
var newUL = $('<ul />',{'id' : 'menu-css'}).insertBefore('table.catsTable');
$('table.catsTable').find('a').each(function(){
    $(this).wrap('<li></li>').parent().appendTo(newUL);
}).closest('ul').next('table').remove();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/HBnMm/).

References:

- [`appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/).
- [`closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/).
- [`insertBefore()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/).
- [`next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).
- [`parent()`](http://api.jquery.com/parent/).
- [`remove()`](http://api.jquery.com/remove/).
- [`wrap()`](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/).

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should try this fix:

```
<script>
    $('.catsTable').find('td').each(function(){
         $(this).replaceWith('<li>'+$(this).html()+'</li>);
    });
    $('.catNumData').remove();
</script>
```

I fixed some of your syntax. You had some extra $() that I deleted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all the table with the `<ul>`, you could do something like:

```
$('.catsTable').after('<ul id="menu-css">' + 
    '<li><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_2/6">Sezonul 2</a></li>' +
    '<li><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_3/7">Sezonul 3</a></li>' +
    '<li><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_4/8">Sezonul 4</a></li>' +
    '<li><a href="/prison_break_online/sezonul_5/9">Sezonul 4</a></li>' +
'</ul>').first().remove();
```

I hope I'm not misunderstanding what you want...